# Symfony4 external routes of a bundle

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Hi I am migrating to symfony4 from 2.7. I do have couple bundles and I followed the instructions: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/external_resources.html

My config/bundle.php:

```
...
App\Frontend\MainBundle\FrontendMainBundle::class => ['all' => true],
...
```

My config/routes.yaml:

```
frontend_main:
    resource: "@AppFrontendMainBundle/Resources/config/routing.frontend.main.yml"
               #also tried here without App
```

I got a message:

Unrecognized option "resource" under "frontend_main".

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I pasted in your resource code and got a Bundle does not exist message.  Not surprising because I don't have the bundle.  The unrecognized error seems more like a formatting/indention error.  Is there anything else in config/routing.yaml?

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony 4 with Flex directory structure the default routing file is called `config/routes.yaml`, not `routing.yaml`. Are you sure the file is loaded as part of the routing and not as a service configuration?

You should check your routing config Kernel in `src/Kernel.php`. By default it looks like this:

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes)
{
    $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config';
    if (is_dir($confDir.'/routes/')) {
        $routes->import($confDir.'/routes/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
    }
    if (is_dir($confDir.'/routes/'.$this->environment)) {
        $routes->import($confDir.'/routes/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
    }
    $routes->import($confDir.'/routes'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
}
```

You can just rename the last import (or add another one) if you want to keep your file name:

```
$routes->import($confDir.'/routing'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
```

Comment: Yes, it is default. And sorry, just was a spelling error. It is of course routes.yaml. The absolut defaults of symfony4.